Is the fibration in algebraic geometry a fibration in topology?
In different literatures on algebraic geometry, the term  "fibration" has various definitions (in some papers, it is even defined to be a certain special rational map). We fix the setting here.
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two complex analytic spaces, and $f:X\to Y$ be a surjective and proper holomorphic map. We call $f$ a AG-fibration if every fiber of $f$ is connected.
We adopt the definition in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibration for the T-fibration (topological), i.e. if it satisfies the homotopy lifting property for all topological spaces.

I want to ask: Is an AG-fibration a T-fibration?


I think you might want to add a condition of being flat to your definition of AG-fibration. I would not think of a blowup as being a fibration.

In AG fibers need not be homotopy-equivalent to each other.

The ideas are related, but not the same as the following two examples show.
Let's suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is a proper smooth morphism of algebraic varieties over $\Bbb{C}$. If we analytify this, it corresponds to a submersive map of complex manifolds with compact fibres and by Ehresmann's theorem this is a fibre bundle of smooth manifolds. In particular, if $Y$ is connected then all of the fibres are diffeomorphic manifolds. This gives us fibration in a very strong sense.
I mentioned in the comments that it is probably best to impose a flatness condition to get a notion of fibration in algebraic (or analytic) geometry. However, in this case one can take the flat family over $\Bbb{A}^1$ given by (closures in $\Bbb{P}^2$ of) the curves $xy-t^2$ in $\Bbb{A}^2\times \Bbb{A}^1$. Over $t=0$, the corresponding curve is topologically a wedge sum of two $\Bbb{P}^1$'s or equivalently a wedge sum of two $S^2$'s. Over $t\ne 0$, this is just a copy of $\Bbb{P}^1$. In particular, the homotopy type is generically $S^2$, but over $t=0$ it is a wedge sum of a pair of $S^2$'s. So, the fibres are not homotopic and in particular this is not a fibration in the sense of homotopy theory.

+1, nice answer with Ehresmann's theorem demonstrating how close the desired statement is to true. I should have included that in mine!

Under these definitions, no. Consider the projection of $V(y^2z-x^3-az^3)\subset\Bbb P^2\times\Bbb A^1$ to $\Bbb A^1$, where $a$ is the coordinate on $\Bbb A^1$ and $x,y,z$ are the coordinates on $\Bbb P^2$. Then the fiber over every point is a nonempty connected projective curve, so it's an AG-fibration by your definition, but the fibers over $a\neq 0$ are elliptic curves, homotopy equivalent to a torus, and the fiber over $a=0$ is homotopy equivalent to the 2-sphere. Since there are different homotopy classes of fibers, it cannot be a T-fibration.
